# Parallel collection for unique string counting

Tags: rust

I need some highly parallelized collection something like java concurrent skiplist. The general task: I am working on a server for counting unique words in all messages the server gets. I don't care what the words are only the count. Once in a while, I get a get_count message I reset the counter and start all over.

But I am always bottlenecked on the post_words function. The same thing in java runs 5s in rust 80s. I have tried the experimental skiplist set from the crossbeam. I got the same result. The other issue is string allocation.  Any ideas?

```rust
//Dashset from https://docs.rs/dashmap/4.0.2/dashmap/struct.DashSet.html
type Words = DashSet<String>;

let set: Arc<Words> = Arc::new(DashSet::with_capacity(100000));

// for each new socket I create
let set = set.clone();

//Word processing
fn post_words(client: i32, data: Vec<u8>, db: &Words) -> Response {
    let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(data.as_slice());
    let mut input = String::new();
    decoder.read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();

    //The bottleneck
    for word in  input.split_whitespace() {
        db.insert(String::from(word));
    }


    let mut response = Response::new();
    response.status = Response_Status::OK;
    return  response
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to decode the entire data before splitting words? The staff is done twice I suppose

Comment: Obligatory questions: You compiled with `--release`, right? `String`s in Rust are UTF-8 (not sure whether this is different from Java, though), which may incur more overhead than I initially thought. Do you really need to convvert `data` to string and convert `word` to a string afterwards? Can't you just iterate over the `data` (keeping raw bytes, i.e. `u8`) and store `Vec<u8>` (instead of `String`) in the `DashSet` (thereby avoiding potential UTF-8 checks and assertions)?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't need to know the words a can only keep a hash. Now I don't have to allocate string for each word. This improved my solution from 80s to 1.7s

```rust
type Words = DashSet<u64>;

async fn post_words(client: i32, data: Vec<u8>, db: &Words) -> Response {
    let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(data.as_slice());
    let mut input = String::new();
    decoder.read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();


    for word in  input.split_whitespace() {
        let mut s = DefaultHasher::new();
        word.hash(&mut s);
        db.insert( s.finish());
    }


    let mut response = Response::new();
    response.status = Response_Status::OK;
    return  response
}
```